# Как изменить размер вводимого текста в EditText, не меняя уже напечатанный текст

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Я пытаюсь сделать EditText, в котором по нажатию на кнопку будет меняться размер вводимого текста, а уже напечатанный будет прежнего размера, но когда я пытаюсь применить метод setTextSize(), он также меняет уже напечатанный текст, что не соответствует моим требованиям.
Зарание Спасибо, за любые предложения, и да, я пишу код на языке Java в Android Studio

Comment: Сделать текст разного размера в одном поле ввода можно, наверное только спанами. Тут пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16335416/15923106, но задача усложняется тем, что вы его редактируете - скорее всего вам придётся повесить слушатель ввода (`addTextChangedListener()`) и в нём бороться со спанами.

Comment: woess, спасибо, ваш ответ помог мне решить проблему, но мое приложение стало работать очень медленно из-за спанов, я думаю это потому что я создаю новый объект AbsoluteSizeSpan при каждом добавления символа с клавиатуры, вы не знаете как мне избежать этой задержки в работе?

Comment: Не знаю, тем более неизвестно как вы это реализовали. Думаю лучше задать новый вопрос по этой проблеме, приложить ваш код и пояснить что вас в нём не устраивает